# A word that describes a smooth and feel-good transition

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there a good adjective that describes the experience of entering from one magical world to another as a very smooth, magical yet almost like real and feel-good way?

I thought of a few like say "sleek" experience between the two worlds, "neat" experience between the two worlds, etc. But all of these words sound not enough to give that smooth and feel good effect.

Comment: Either too localised, or belongs on writers.se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One sense of verb *[morph](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/morph)* is "to undergo dramatic change in a seamless and barely noticeable fashion."  Wiktionary marks this sense as colloquial and says the word is a shortening of *[metamorphose](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/metamorphose)*, to change in shape or form.

Along the lines of previously-suggested *seamless* and *comfortable* transitions, one might also say *[indiscernible](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/indiscernible) transition*.  In place of *transition* one might use *bridge*, *[segue](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/segue)*, *[mutation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mutation)* or *[transmutation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transmutation)*.  Also consider the sense of 
*[mercurial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mercurial)* that means "Lively; clever; sprightly; animated; quick-witted."

Answer (score 4):

Something like a *seamless transition*?

Comment: Thanks! I actually had used the word "sleek" in an earlier sentence and was hoping to find another word to avoid repetition, and possibly a slightly magical feel.

Comment: The music nerd in me wanted to say *crystal glissando*.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the person had a *comfortable transition*. This implies that nothing went wrong - it was smooth - and that the person felt good.